# SequenceWaiter doesn't recognize my event

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit, parsley

I'm using this [AsyncHelper](http://blog.darrenbishop.com/2011/04/darren-on-flex-flexunit4-testing-with_19.html). I would like to create basic test case where I would like to dispatch event from the test method (by Parsley MessageDispatcher), catch this event in any other method and dispatch it back (by flex EventDispatcher).

This is my test case:

`package flexUnitTests { 
    import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;`

```
import flexUnitTests.events.TestEvent;
import flexUnitTests.helpers.AsyncHelper;

import mx.logging.Log;
import mx.logging.LogEventLevel;
import mx.logging.targets.TraceTarget;

import org.flexunit.assertThat;
import org.hamcrest.object.equalTo;
import org.spicefactory.parsley.core.context.Context;
import org.spicefactory.parsley.core.messaging.MessageProcessor;
import org.spicefactory.parsley.dsl.context.ContextBuilder;
import org.spicefactory.parsley.flex.FlexConfig;
import org.spicefactory.parsley.flex.FlexContextBuilder;

public class HelloTest extends AsyncHelper {

    [MessageDispatcher]
    public var dispatcher:Function;

    [Inject]
    public var context:Context;

    public var eventDispatcher:EventDispatcher;

    [Before]
    public function initializeContext():void {
        // Use ContextBuilder to build context
        var context:Context = ContextBuilder.newSetup()
            .newBuilder()
            .config(FlexConfig.forClass(ParsleyConfig))
            .build();

        // Add this test case to context 
        context.addDynamicObject(this);

        eventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    }

    [After]
    public function destroyContext():void {
        eventDispatcher = null;
    }

    [MessageHandler(selector='TestEvent.ok')]
    public function passItOn(event:TestEvent):void {
        eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    [Test(async)]
    public function tryIt():void {
        dispatcher(new TestEvent(TestEvent.OK));
        waitFor(eventDispatcher, TestEvent.OK, 2000);
        thenAssert(function(event:TestEvent, data:*):void {
            assertThat(event.type, equalTo('TestEvent.ok'));
        });
    }
}
```

}

And my Event looks like this:

`package flexUnitTests.events
{
    import flash.events.Event;`

```
public class TestEvent extends Event
{
    static public const OK :String = "TestEvent.ok";

    public function TestEvent(type:String)
    {
        super(type);
    }
}
```

}

I don't know where is a problem. If I made traces at code, I can see that Parsley dispatch my event into passItOn method. And flex EventDispatcher dispatch event back. But I don't know why SequenceWaiter doesn't recognize my event.

Comment: I don't understand; there is no SequenceWaiter in your code.  What is that and why do you expect it to recongnize your event?

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of this test.  You're just testing out parsley's event bus? Jens Halm is already doing that before any release.  Unit testing shouldn't really be about the framework, but small, testable pieces of code.  Furthermore, you're asking us to debug (for you) some 3rd party class made by some random dude online which I've never seen before.  I say bring it up with him.  Voting to close.

Comment: Hi, there is a testCase without that class...
[link]http://www.emte.cz/flex/HandlingEventsTest_part2.as 
And this is my [link]http://www.emte.cz/flex/TestEvent.as 

I'm just learning here how to create this type of tests. After that  I would like to dispatch some event to any class and try to catch any other event. There is only one event dispatched by Parsley and then dispatched by Flex. It is just for some example how to work with it - and no other sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see where is a problem now:
It's because I call dispatcher() before creating sequence. It I change order of calling methods problem disappear.